# how to write dynamic sql, with Multiple variables

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with customer,
I want to build function or sp that return the customers by their city,
It should allow enter Multiple variables.
How can i do it?

Comment: what have you tried so far & what would you like the output to look like? it helps if you give us something to work with.

Answer (score 0):

I'm supposing that you mean that the stored procedure has to accept some parameters.

You can do it by going to your Database in SSMS, Programmability, and right click on "stored procedures" and choose "New Stored procedure". It will generate a template for you where you can see the form of it:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE <Procedure_Name, sysname, ProcedureName> 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    <@Param1, sysname, @p1> <Datatype_For_Param1, , int> = <Default_Value_For_Param1, , 0>, 
    <@Param2, sysname, @p2> <Datatype_For_Param2, , int> = <Default_Value_For_Param2, , 0>
AS

Ex: CREATE PROCEDURE MYPROC @PARAM1 INT, @PARAM2 NVARCHAR(MAX) AS ...
```

I hope it helps,

Roger

Comment: So if have 30 city, i need to set 30 variables?

Comment: No, only one @city variable, and your select code should include something like 'where CITY=@city ... Maybe, I'm missing something in your question ?

Comment: i want that the query return in one run: all coustomer from 'ny' in the secound run all 'ny' and 'la' and 'london'

Comment: I think that instead of returning the results that way you could call the stored procedure as many times as needed, or maybe return a temporary table with each record containing a field that indicates which city is related to.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20815/Building-Dynamic-SQL-In-a-Stored-Procedure) may be helpful just to prepare dynamic query. If you want to pass N-number of values for specific parameter then you should use UserDefinedType(even UserDefinedTable type).

TO USE A STORED PROCEDURE WITH DATATABLE AS PARAMETER(STRUCTURED DATA TYPE)

```
1.CREATE CUSTOM STRUCTURE TYPE INDATABASE
    EX.
    CREATE TYPE [CUSTOM_DATATYPE_NAME] AS TABLE (FIELD_NAME DATATYPE,...)
2.CREATE STORED PROCEDURE WITH CUSTOM PARAMS 
    EX.
    CREATE PROCEDURE [PROCEDURE_NAME] (@[VARIABLE_NAME] CUSTOM_DATATYPE_NAME READONLY,...)
3.USE ABOVE CUSTOM_DATATYPE_NAME DIRECTLY IN INSERT, UPDATE STATEMENT
4.IN CS FILE (IN CODE TO CALL THIS PROCEDURE AND PASS DATA TABLE)

    SqlCommand sqCom = new SqlCommand();
        sqCom.CommandText = "[PROCEDURE_NAME]";
        sqCom.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        sqCom.Parameters.Add("@[VARIABLE_NAME]", SqlDbType.Structured);
        sqCom.Parameters.Add("@Notice", SqlDbType.VarChar, 300);
        sqCom.Parameters.Add("@InsertedBy", SqlDbType.Int);

        sqCom.Parameters[0].Value = [DATA_TABLE];
        sqCom.Parameters[1].Value = Notice;
        sqCom.Parameters[2].Value = userid;
        sqCom.Connection = conSQL;
        sqCom.Connection.Open();

        int affectedRows=sqCom.ExecuteNonQuery();
        sqCom.Connection.Close();
        return affectedRows;
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a stored procedure that allowed one parameter (`@inSelectFilter`) where the user can enter a select statement

Then, within the SP, I split it into a table variable and build it into a complete WHERE statement to pass dynamically to a select statement

```
--BUILD THE INDIVIDUAL SELECT STATEMENTS INTO A TEMP TABLE
    SET @RowPosition = 1;
    SET @inSelectFilter = @inSelectFilter + ';';
    SET @inSelectFilter = REPLACE(@inSelectFilter,'/','''');
    WHILE LEN(@inSelectFilter) > 0
    BEGIN
        IF PATINDEX('%;%',@inSelectFilter) > 0
        BEGIN
            SET @SelectParameter = SUBSTRING(@inSelectFilter, 0, PATINDEX('%;%',@inSelectFilter))
            SET @inSelectFilter = SUBSTRING(@inSelectFilter, LEN(@SelectParameter + ';') + 1,LEN(@inSelectFilter))
            IF @RowPosition = 1
                BEGIN
                INSERT INTO @SelectParameterTable VALUES ('WHERE ' + @SelectParameter)
                END
            ELSE
                BEGIN
                INSERT INTO @SelectParameterTable VALUES (' AND ' + @SelectParameter)
                END
            SET @RowPosition = @RowPosition + 1        
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            SET @SelectParameter = @inSelectFilter
            SET @inSelectFilter = NULL
        END
    END

    --BUILD THE COMPLETE WHERE STATEMENT
    SET @SelectParameter = NULL;
    SELECT @SelectParameter = COALESCE(@SelectParameter, '') + statementString FROM @SelectParameterTable 
    SET @SelectParameterTemp = @SelectParameter;
    Print 'Selection statement: ' + @SelectParameter
```

The only thing to bear in mind is to have some sort of escape character instead of the ' so that the parameter can be passed

So the SP is

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [usp_FindMembers] (@inSelectFilter NVARCHAR(1000))
```

and is executed as an example like this...

```
exec usp_FindMembers 'STATUS=/A/ OR (STATUS IN (/N/,/PC/,/PD/,/PE/,/PN/) AND PAYGROUP IN (/X1/,/C1/,/X3/,/T2/))'
```